# How can I share R shiny App internally without data breach?

Tags: r, shiny, data-security

I have developed a shiny App by installing R and R studio within local sever of my company and now I want to share app with my team.

Our data is sensitive and

1. I don't want my code and data go out of our server.
2. I don't want to deploy in shinyapp.io
3. I don't want to use Rstudio connect now (we plan to use this option later)

Please suggest a way that confirm data and code are 100% safe

Thanks

Comment: What about a shiny server? You can deploy your app there, and only people within your intranet will have access to the app, and no one will see the code unless they have access to the computer that is running the app. https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/

Comment: Thank you.. is it the same case with rstudio connect i.e. only who have access to our systems can have access app and data?

Comment: Well I haven't used rstudio connect, but I use daily the shiny server. The way it works is that you take a computer, and you install the server, and then deploy your shiny apps in it. Then people within your intranet will access to the shiny app that you have develop through the IP of that computer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the details.. if possible can you share details of key docs for shiny server

Comment: You are welcome. You can find everything in the link I sent you before, here is the manual https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/ and there are a few blogs and youtube links to guide you through the installation but it's fairly simple.